# Check for multiple conditions and sum values in a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to solve a conditional-problem in excel which is very similar to this
[question](https://superuser.com/questions/171796/excel-how-to-sum-values-in-a-column-based-on-multiple-criteria)

However I need  to do the following:

*If*

product code in range `A1:A100` = A certain code

*and*

month in range `B1:B100` (format `24/06/2011`)= a certain month (numerical value e.g. 6)

*then*

sum all numbers in column `C1:C100` for which the above conditions are true

---

So far I am using an additional table where I check the condition for each row
and afterwards I sum up all occurences in this additional table. but I feel that there is a way to get rid of this additional table.

One of the key prblems seems to be the extraction of the month from a date range within a sumproduct or countifs function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter as an array formula (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=SUM(($A$1:$A$100="Your Code")*(MONTH($B$1:$B$100)=6)*$C$1:$C$100)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It is working now. Arrays in excel escaped me for years as it seems....