# Excel sum if based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to sum values in one column where two other columns meet certain criteria.

Column A has the item name
Column F has its value
Column G has the date it was bought

What I need to do is get the sales value from Col F for each item individually from A but for different months from G
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried SUMIFS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: How to sum values in a column based on multiple criteria](http://superuser.com/questions/171796/excel-how-to-sum-values-in-a-column-based-on-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 1):

You need the `SUMIFS` function. For example:

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,A:A,some_criteria,G:G,some_criteria)
```

Try that out and let us know if you struggle with anything.

If you want to compare months you might be better off creating another column containing the month numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [sumproduct](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) here

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(G1:G7)=1)*(A1:A7="a")*F1:F7)
```

Check if the month is January (1) AND item is "a" to SUM column F

adjust as needed. e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(G:G)=1)*(A:A="a")*F:F)
```

This roughly translates to `sum(True*True*F)` or `sum(1*1*F)` if they match.